# Where can I find detailed information about passports of different countries worldwide?

Tags: passports

Is there an online resource with comprehensive descriptions of the passports of different countries, including what information they contain, what security features they have, and typical validity period.

Comment: It's not a global database but [PRADO](http://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/prado-start-page.html) might be relevant.

Comment: Perhaps you want [ICAO Document 9303](http://www.icao.int/Security/mrtd/Pages/Document9303.aspx)?

Comment: You won't get a resource with _all_ security features -- in fact, the relevant ICAO document strongly recommends that there should be secret security features whose nature and details are known only to the issuing government.

Answer (score 7):

Is there an online resource about virtually anything and everything?  Why yes, it's **Wikipedia**!  More specifically:

- Information contained in passports: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biometric_passport (see also [ICAO Document 9303](http://www.icao.int/Security/mrtd/Pages/Document9303.aspx) if you really want to know *everything* about passport standards)
- Security features can be found under the entries for individual passports, eg. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_passport#Security_features_2

  - For the European Union, [PRADO](http://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/prado-start-page.html) is a great resource with data and pictures.  For example, [here are all the public security features of the current Irish passport](http://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/6508/index.html).
- Passport validity around the world: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passport_validity
- ...and lots and lots more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Passports